# How to communicate serial port using multithreading in c# for zigbee modules?

Tags: c#, multithreading, zigbee

I need to build simple chat application using Zigbee (Rx/Tx) modules....

Two zigbee end (rx module) receive... data...

Another two zigbee end (tx module) sending...data...

Each module call separately... should maintained their communication...

For example:

> Arx, Atx (Alice)
>   Brx, Btx (Bob)
>
> Atx send, Brx receive, display the text... Btx send, Arx receive,
>   display the text...

How to begin, how to progress, how to finish.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this URL, it might help.

http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/microsoft-net-framework-zigbee-library

Comment: how to write code like you bro, can you teach me bro... how to start, how to progress and how to finish...

Comment: May I ask you a question? Are you familiar with C# programming in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes bro... I know visual studio.. little bit know about c# (C Program background)